# How can I import a Modul from folder

Tags: import, module, spyder

I work with spyder and have a problem to import of modul from folder.

What I did:

- 1- create a folder with name **"Modul"** on my desktop.
- 2- create `__init__.py` in this folder.
- 3- create `hallo.py` in this folder.

I wrote in hallo.py:

```
def welt():
    print("Hallo Welt")
    
def mars():
    print("Hallo Mars")
```

Now I want to use this syntax to run ***welt*** function:

```
from Modul import hallo
hallo.welt()
```

But it doesn't work and have this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Modul'
```

What should I do or what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The import statement depends on where is your importing file and implementing file. In your case, its where is `hallo.py` file and a file where you will write `import` statement.

like, if your implementing file and `hallo.py` is in same folder then you should use:

`import hallo`

and if your folder structure is like this:

```
|module_folder
|---->hallo.py
|---->__init__.py
|implement.py
```

then you should use:

```
from module_folder import hallo
```

to import from the folder you need to create an empty file name `__init__.py` else it won't work.